# Bash script upload to ftp & delete files 7 days and older

Tags: bash

The script is unable to delete anything older than 7 days in FTP. Says the error "550 Can't remove directory: No such file or directory" All of the FTP backups are just in the main directory.

```
#!/bin/sh
USERNAME="user"
PASSWORD="pass"
SERVER="ftpbackupservergoeshere"
NOW="$(date +'%m-%d-%Y')"

DAYS=7
RMDATE=$(date --iso -d  $DAYS' days ago')

# local directory to pickup *.tar.gz file
FILE="/root/$NOW.tar.gz"

cd /home/minecraft/multicraft/servers
find . -name \*.log -type f -delete
find . -name \*.log.gz -type f -delete
cd

tar -zcf $NOW.tar.gz /home/minecraft

# login to remote server
ftp -n -v $SERVER <<EOF 
user $USERNAME $PASSWORD
binary 
put $FILE $NOW.tar.gz
cd ..
rm -rf ${RMDATE}
bye

EOF

rm /root/$NOW.tar.gz
```

Comment: You upload `$NOW.tar.gz` but try to delete `${RMDATE}`. Should you be deleting `${RMDATE}.tar.gz`?

Comment: try : `find /path/to/files* -mtime +7 -exec rm {} \;`

Comment: ISO date format is `'%Y-%m-%d'`, not `'%m-%d-%Y'` as on line 5. Use `set -x` to trace the actual commands and variable expansion.